# Why does my saved Tensorflow model predict nonsense when I restore it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, model, conv-neural-network

I trained a convolutional neural network in Tensorflow, which analyzes images and counts objects in them, and saved it for later. Now I am trying to restore the model and predict values for images cut into tiles. What I get though, are nonsense values and almost the same number for each tile. Each loaded model gives numbers around a specific value, same for each image but different for each model.
I am thinking that maybe I am using the wrong tensor from the restored model?
Here is an excerpt from my code:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 98, 98, 3], name='x')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, ], name='y') 

# create two convolutional layers: layer1 and layer2

s3 = create_conv_layer_for_sum(layer2, f2, f3, [5, 5], 2, outf_sum, name='s_layer3')
y_pred = s3

error = tf.pow((y - y_pred), 2)
# other error measures also present
optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(error)
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # train the model here
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
        save_path = saver.save(sess, "models/model"+str(num)+"/model.ckpt")


def create_conv_layer_for_sum(input_data, num_input_channels, num_filters, filter_shape, stride, out_fction, name):
    # ...
    sum = tf.reduce_sum(transformed, axis=[1, 2, 3], name=name+'_output')
    return sum
```

This part is the training and saving.
Then I restore the model:

```
    sess = tf.Session()

    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('models/' + model + '/model.ckpt.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, 'models/' + model + '/model.ckpt')

    inputData = CNNutils.load_photo(photo, 98)  # cuts photo into squares and stacks those as a numpy array

    graph = tf.get_default_graph()

    x = graph.get_tensor_by_name('x:0')

    s3 = graph.get_tensor_by_name('s_layer3_output:0')

    y_pred = tf.reduce_sum(s3)

    pred, sum3 = sess.run([y_pred, s3], feed_dict={x: inputData})
    print(pred)
    print(sum3)
```

`s3` should be the output of the last layer and then `y_pred` adds up the predictions for the whole image from individual tiles.

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you save the model using `model.save` and restore the model using `load_model`.

Keras supports a simpler interface to save both the model weights and model architecture together into a single H5 file.

Saving the model with `model.save` way includes everything we need to know about the model, including:

1. Model weights.
2. Model architecture.
3. Model compilation details (loss and metrics).
4. Model optimizer state.

Saved model can then be loaded by calling the `load_model()` function and passing the filename. The function returns the model with the same architecture and weights.

You can find the example about save and load of the model [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60198878/proper-way-to-save-model-in-keras).