# Proper Way to Save Model in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

I have been trying to implement transfer learning in my research. I have decided to go with VGG16 as provided in `keras.applications`.

I load the model and freeze its weights as follows:

```py
vgg16 = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False,input_shape=(img_rows, img_cols, 3), pooling = None)
for layer in vgg16.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
```

I then add top layers for classification:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(vgg16)
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

I compile and train the model on my data to warm up the top layers first:

```
EPOCHS = 4000

history = model.fit_generator(datagen_train.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=100),
                        validation_data = datagen_val.flow(X_val, y_val, batch_size=100),
                        epochs = EPOCHS,
                        steps_per_epoch = np.ceil(len(X_train) / 100),
                        validation_steps = np.ceil(len(X_val) / 100),
                        callbacks=[es, mc]
                       )
```

I save the model using the usual Keras command: `save_model`.

My next goal is unfreeze some of the top layers of VGG16 and train the model again (a.k.a fine-tune). However, upon loading the model with `load_model`, I find that the model looks like untrained.I tested it before saving on the test data set and the performance was high in the 70% range. After loading the same model, I find that the performance on the test data set is around 20%, which is almost below chance, considering I have five class labels.

What has happened in between my `save_model` and `load_model` commands?

Comment: Try `model.save()` and `load_model()`.

Comment: That's exactly what I have used.

Comment: I have found out the cause of my problems. After I save the model and load it back for fine tuning, I use fit method to start training it. It turns out that the optimization algorithm takes it away in the very wrong direction very fast, despite the fact that I have set relatively low learning rate of 0.0001. I have fixed it by decreasing the learning rate even further.

Comment: You don't need to compile after loading. It gets compiled automatically with the correct optimizer states.

Answer (score 0):

Keras supports a simpler interface to save both the model weights and model architecture together into a single H5 file.

Saving the model with save.model way includes everything we need to know about the model, including:

1. Model weights.
2. Model architecture.
3. Model compilation details (loss and metrics).
4. Model optimizer state.

Saved model can then be loaded by calling the load_model() function and passing the filename. The function returns the model with the same architecture and weights.

**Example:** I have run a simple model and saved using model.save and the did the load with load_model of keras.  You can download the dataset from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv).

**Build and Save the Model:**

```
# MLP for Pima Indians Dataset saved to single file
import numpy as np
from numpy import loadtxt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# load pima indians dataset
dataset = np.loadtxt("/content/pima-indians-diabetes.csv", delimiter=",")

# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:8]
Y = dataset[:,8]

# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Model Summary
model.summary()

# Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)

# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y, verbose=0)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))

# save model and architecture to single file
model.save("model.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")
```

Output -

```
Model: "sequential_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 12)                108       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 8)                 104       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 9         
=================================================================
Total params: 221
Trainable params: 221
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
acc: 77.08%
Saved model to disk
```

**Load the Model and Evaluate to verify:**

```
# load and evaluate a saved model
from numpy import loadtxt
from keras.models import load_model

# load model
model = load_model('model.h5')

# summarize model.
model.summary()

# load dataset
dataset = loadtxt("pima-indians-diabetes.csv", delimiter=",")

# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:8]
Y = dataset[:,8]

# evaluate the model
score = model.evaluate(X, Y, verbose=0)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], score[1]*100))
```

Output -

```
Model: "sequential_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 12)                108       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 8)                 104       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 9         
=================================================================
Total params: 221
Trainable params: 221
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
acc: 77.08%
```